# Duration Calculator in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been studying Python by myself since a month ago.
I want to make a duration calculator that shows the total time of each different duration.
For instance, there are two different flights I have to take, and I want to get the total time I would be in the airplanes. It goes like this.

```
a = input('Enter the duration: ') #11h40m
b = input('Enter the duration: ') #13h54m


#it may show the total duration
01d01h34m
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

**Edit** : I tried to use strftime to format the 'duration' but had some issues with day.
So I did it manually (you can format it the way you wish)

```
import datetime
import time

# Convert str to strptime
a_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("11h40m", "%Hh%Mm")
b_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("13h54m", "%Hh%Mm")
# Convert to timedelta
a_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours = a_time.hour,minutes=a_time.minute)
b_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours = b_time.hour,minutes=b_time.minute)

duration = (a_delta + b_delta)

print(str(duration.days) + time.strftime('d%Hh%Mm', time.gmtime(duration.seconds)))

'1d01h34m'
```